# MIPS unsigned operations

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I am working on a project which restricts our usage of the MIPS commands to MicroMIPS. Because of this, I cannot use addu, subu, sltu, etc.

My first question is, is it possible to make these commands out of the twenty-two MicroMIPS instructions?

My second question needs further detail.

I am running into trouble when multiplying two 16-bit numbers using a shift-add algorithm when the resulting answer is a 32 bit number with a 1 as the MSB. At this stage, I would like to take the mod of this answer but because MIPS is interpreting it as a negative number, this is giving me problems as my mod operator only accounts for positive numbers (as it should).

Is there a way I can force MIPS to interpret this number as a positive number? Is there a way I could I modulate somewhere in the shift add multiply algorithm such that I never get such a large answer, yet the answer remains the same?

Thanks for any help here,

Cam.

Comment: MicroMIPS covers most of the MIPS instructions, including `addu`, `subu` (with `addu16`, `subu16` replacement). So do you mean a stricter set of MicroMIPS? And if you do the multiplication by a shift-add algorithm yourself then there should be no problem because add/subtract is no different for signed and unsigned number, and there are `srl16` to shift right logical

Comment: The MicroMIPS set I am using does not include addu/subu/etc. The problem is though, once the MSB is a 1, the number is a two's complement negative, and this gives me an incorrect modulo result. How can I make this be interpreted as positive without addu/subu?

Comment: What's your code? And what specific instruction set are you using? Because I looked in the ISA and there are addu16, subu16...